# Why doesn't Google Maps Location history work reliably with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, google-maps

I just switched from an Android phone to an iPhone. With the Android phone, my location history was perfect, with the iPhone it is all confused.

In Google Map app I've set Settings → Personal Content → Location History to **Always**.  I also have `Background App Refresh` enabled in the Settings app.

The symptom is it sort of works, sometimes location is working, other times it has me "Walking" for 7 hours or "Driving" for 3 hours, or it has me leaving home before I did but arriving at work at the right location. Very sporadic.

How can I get Google Map timeline to reliably track my location on my iPhone XS Max?

Comment: Go to Settings app → Google Maps and see if Background App Refresh is turned on, and Location is set to Always.

Comment: Mine stopped working last December, for no apparent reason at all. I asked Google about it only yesterday. No reply as yet.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes background refresh is enabled and location is `Always`.